# Do providers block transactions sent with a too low gas fee?

Tags: gas-price, eip-1559

I am getting the following error when deploying a contract:

```
ProviderError: err: max fee per gas less than block base fee, address ..., maxFeePerGas: 45000000000 baseFee: 63475853125 (supplied gas 6677305)
```

I am intentionally setting the gasPrice variable to 45gwei. I have done this in the past for costly deployments so that they could be picked up over night or in a few days. Now, (perhaps since eip-1559?) it seems as though the providers are blocking transactions from being sent, whereas before they would just get sent off and mined whenever the gas price dropped enough. I also can't set my gasPrice in MetaMask that low anymore. Is this some new change that came with some eip?

Edit:
I was able to send it off after disabling MetaMask's "advanced gas features" ugh..
Still confused why I couldn't do so when deploying through the console.